# What is the best way to implement a global "last update time" in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am a noob to AngularJS and I'm using it to build a real-time dashboard.

I would like to have the last update time in the upper right-hand corner. This should be updated any time any data changes. I can think of plenty of ways to do this very simply using JQuery, but I'd like to know how best to do it "properly" using AngularJS.

Comment: I'd just create a directive that listens for broadcast events. Any component that triggers an update can broadcast the time

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, that seems like a good place to start. After a bit of reading it looks like $emit might be more suitable?

Comment: `$emit` would only be useful if the directive's scope was a parent of whatever scope *emits* the event. IMO this would be highly unlikely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment, I'd just create a directive that displays the update time

```
.directive('lastUpdateTime', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        template: "Last updated: {{updateTime | date:'short'}}",
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.$on('data-updated', function(e, time) {
                scope.updateTime = time;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Pop it somewhere in your app

```
<p class="upper-right-hand-corner" last-update-time></p>
```

Then simply have any component that updates *data* broadcast the event

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('data-updated', new Date());
```

---

As [Beyers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202913/beyers) mentioned, there may be a performance boost if your directive registers the listener on `$rootScope` and other components use `$rootScope.$emit` instead of `$broadcast`.

Comment: Nice, this is better than my answer

Comment: This is a little non-ideal since your going to be pumping the whole UI to get a singular value. This is the use case for something like a service.

Comment: @msarchet not sure what you mean by *"pumping the whole UI"*. The directive's scope would only be marked dirty when that specific event occurs

Comment: I did phrase that incorrectly. $rootscope.$broadcast does crawl the entire scope chain which is non-ideal.

Comment: @msarchet scopes listen for events on every digest cycle anyway

Comment: @msarchet this is worth reading too. `$broadcast` only sends the event to registered listeners ~ http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2724-scope-broadcast-is-surprisingly-efficient-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: Better to emit on `$rootScope` and register `$rootScope.on`, this way the event is guaranteed only one level of propagation.

Comment: @Beyers not a bad suggestion, you'd just need to be aware of potential listener conflicts on `$rootScope`

Comment: @Phil true, but at least you only need to worry about listener conflicts on `$rootScope` and not the entire scope hierarchy downwards if `$rootScope.$broadcast` is used

Comment: @Beyers seems I'm wrong. The named listeners on any particular scope are stored in an array so there's no chance of conflict

Comment: @Phil I had to double check myself just now :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a global `$rootScope.$broadcast` to do this.

Or so you don't pump the entire UI all the time I'd suggest using a service to handle this.

```
.service('updateTracker', [function() {
  var self = this;
  self.lastUpdateTime = new Date();
  self.updated = function() {
    self.lastUpdateTime = new Date();   
  }
}]);
```

Then you can consume and use this service and value in your UI.